# Closing element tags in php

Tags: php

I have just started to learn PHP from books and have come across something I don't understand. In the book they never close html tags is this correct practice or should they be closed? Here is an example of the books content:

```
    <?php

        $cars = array('Dodge'=>'Viper','Chevrolet'=>'Camaro','Ford'=>'Mustang');
        echo '<dl><dt>Original Element Order:<dd>';
        foreach($cars as $key => $value){
            echo '&bull;', $key.' '.$value;
        }

    ?>
```

Could anyone tell me if this is correct and common practice?
Thanks

Comment: Closing PHP tags in a script isn't a great idea (too easy to have spaces after it - no close tags, no problematic spaces), but as for HTML - best to keep it clean and correct

Answer (score 0):

Some old books :). They definitely need to be closed. 
You need to echo `</dd></dt></dl>` after the foreach loop.

Comment: It's actually a new book 2014 copyright called PHP and MySQL in easy steps! Hmmm I was not impressed when I first opened the book I have to say.

Answer (score 0):

The end tags for the `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements are optional in HTML. The missing `</dl>` is a problem though.

Other issues with this fragment:

- Using `&bull;` for a list instead of list markup
- Using something that looks like a `<ul>` (but is simulated with `&bull;`) for key/value pairs
- Having a `dl` with only one `dt` in it.

Comment: Thanks Quentin, thought as much but wanted to confirm. I really don't want to learn the wrong way!